# how to show clickable precentage of two values on a single button

Tags: jquery, css

im very new in html and css ,basically I have two different values
1-Number of Applicants and 2-Number of positions my basic approach was to show them like the following:

```
<button type="button" id="btnInf"></button>
```

Here is my jquery :

```
$("#btnInf").html('<span style="color:black;font-size:12px" >Number of Applicants:</span>
              <span style="color:black;font-size:23px">' +0+ '</span>
              </br><span style="color:brown;font-size:12px">Number of Positions:</span>
              <span style="color:brown;font-size:23px">' + 8 + '</span>');
```

since I am new I have no idea how to show them on a button but using about approach which is not smart,i want to show them on a single clickable button or anything, which shows percentage by color and the number;

Comment: Why do you need to use javascript? Can't you just write it as html?

Comment: @MoshFeu I don't know how really,i found this on internet

Comment: @mortezasol what to write span inside button using html?? `<button><span></span></button>`

Comment: @mortezasol or you want it dinamic???

Comment: @mortezasol I'm afraid you learn a bit html to deal with. Don't you think? Sorry but it's pretty basic for this forum.. For your question, you can copy / paste all of the string and just put it in the html (just remove the `+` symbols of course.

Comment: @MoshFeu thanks but do you have any idea how should I show what I ask in my question?

Comment: @ what do you mean?לבנימלכה

Comment: See my last part of my comment, I explained this.

Comment: @mortezasol see my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Here is nicer code:**

```
<button type="button" id="btnInf">
   <span class="small-font a" >Number of Applicants:</span>
   <span class="big-font a">0</span>
              </br>
   <span class="small-font b">Number of Positions:</span>
   <span class="big-font b">8</span>
</button>
```

**css:**

```
.small-font{
font-size:12px
}
.big-font{
font-size:23px
}
.a{
color:black;
}
.b{
color:brown
}
```

Comment: you can stay `style` inside `span` but it is nicer and corect code

Comment: Tell me if u need help